# Install MinGW for SUSE Linux

Tags: qt, mingw, opensuse

Where do I get a link to install Qt with the MinGW cross compiler in Linux?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Compiling applications for windows while working under linux? Then follow Alan Haggai Alavis post. If your are doing going to do development (e.g. in C) and just want to run it under Linux you can use the GCC compiler package which is available for basically all flavours of linux

Comment: You have asked almost identical question(s) before. If you need additional clarification on a question it is better to update the existing question. If you keep asking the *same* question over and over, they will be closed and/or deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at:

- [Building a Cross compiler for Windows on Linux](http://silmor.de/39)
- [MinGW cross compiler for Linux build environment](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/LinuxCrossMinGW)

Comment: Hi, did you succeed in cross compiling Qt apps on linux? in an answer to the previous similar question you said you had not been able to do that yet..

Comment: @harshath.jr: Hi. I have not yet succeeded in doing so.

Comment: ok.. u mean ther's nothin called as QT with MinGW..right ??
so pls tel me which cross compiler should i use in Linux with QT??
is Mingw only for windows or can i install it in Linux to generate windows executable???

Comment: @suse: You can build a MingW cross-compiler in Linux by following the above articles. Then, you can build executables for Windows by using this cross-compiler.

Comment: MinGW is installed in Linux:)

Answer (score 2):

All you need is just three commands from you:

```
zypper ar http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/windows:/mingw:/win32/openSUSE_11.3/ mingw
zypper mr -r mingw # this makes the repository auto-refresh on next zypper operations
zypper install mingw32-libqt4-devel
```

change 11.3 to to the openSUSE version you have.

The dependencies for .exe compiled through that toolchain can be resolved by fetching .dll files from /usr/i686-pc-mingw32/sys-root/i686-pc-mingw32/bin/ directory.

Answer (score 1):

Fedora 11 comes with the MinGW cross compiler (mingw32-gcc, mingw32-g++, etc.) and Win32 packages for Qt (mingw32-qt). You could try using Fedora instead of SUSE, or the packages may install on SUSE with a bit of coaxing.

Answer (score 0):

There is no link. [MinGW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW) (Minimalist GNU for Windows) is platform specific and Windows-only. On [SUSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SUSE_Linux_distributions), the required compiler GCC and all its dependencies should already be present, so MinGW is unneccessary there.

For [Qt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_%28toolkit%29) for Linux, head over to the [Trolltech Download page](http://www.qtsoftware.com/downloads).

Comment: you misunderstand the question: he wants to use MinGW, not GCC. Reason: he wants windows bindaries to be generated!